# why using document.write doesn't show text on the browser

Tags: javascript, html, document.write

I have this code one is a js file, the other is html file, the problem is when i run the code the browser doesnt show the text in functions document.write(...), someone can help me?

```js
function prose(name, campany){
    this.name= name;
    this.company = company;
    this.rate = rate; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    
</head>
<body>
    
    <script> 
        var y = new prose("JavaScript", "Packt Publishing");
        y.rate(50);
        document.write("The name of the book is " + y.name+ "<br>");
        document.write("The name of the publishing company is : " + y.company + "<br>");
        document.write("The cost of the book is $" + y.sellingPrice+ "<br>");
    </script> 
       
    <!--Ejemplo 5
    <a href="javascript:PacktPub()">Click Here</a> -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: prose is a function .. not a class? Thus, it errors out. JS is synchronous, so nothing after the error is executed

Comment: There is probably an error. Have you opened the console to look?

Comment: becuase Prose is defined after you use it. The code is written before the the closing body tag.

Comment: It crashed because you wrote campany instead of company in your function declaration and rate is also missing. Replace `function prose(name, campany){` by `function prose(name, company, rate){`. Last things, `y.rate(50)` does not work, `y.rate = 50` will.

Comment: Did you read about how to debugging code inside a web browser? If you press f12 key, all major browser open a window commonly called developer tools. Inside this window, you get all information about info or errors about various parts of the browser and some tools for debugging. Principaly, the console tab will be your main friend.

Comment: @treyBake The function is an object constructor using javascript's prototype system. The "classes" that were added in ES6 are just syntactic sugar that hook into this system under the hood.

Comment: @Cat well that's confusing ... seems like really bad design IMO. To me, a function !== a class

Comment: @treyBake `a function !== a class` is totally right, but javascript is one of a group of languages that uses prototype-based inheritance instead of class-based inheritance. It doesn't actually have any classes at all. You can partially ignore this when you're using the new `class` keyword, but there are a lot of situations where the differences matter, and assuming inheritance will work like it does in  C++ could drive you loopy.

Comment: @Cat pfft I'll stick to PHP then haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

  </head>

  <body>

    <script>
      function prose(name, company) {
        this.name = name,
          this.company = company,
          this.rate = 0
      }

      var y = new prose("JavaScript", "Packet Publishing");
      y.rate = 30;
      document.write("The name of the book is " + y.name + "<br>");
      document.write("The name of the publishing company is : " + y.company + "<br>");
      document.write("The cost of the book is $" + y.rate + "<br>");

    </script>

    <!--Ejemplo 5
    <a href="javascript:PacktPub()">Click Here</a> -->
  </body>

</html>
```

You had some syntax errors (campany -> company, rate -> sellingPrice).

Comment: The way he uses a function to create an object is right. A function can be seen as a constructor and calling `new` on this function will create an object. The problem here is just that this function crashes and stop the code.

Answer (score 0):

You have several mistakes.
First of all, you are referencing `company` and it does not exist as you wrote `campany`.

Change to:

`function prose(name, company)`

Second, `prose` is a function, not a class, so it does not recognize the `new` you are invoking. To fix that, either remove the `new` or change it to be a class:

```
let prose = (() =>{

    function prose(name, company, rate) {
        this.name= name;
        this.company = company;
        this.rate = rate; 
    }

    return prose;

})();
```

And also fix the way you are setting the rate.

```
y.rate = 50;
```

Comment: The way he uses a function to create an object is right. A function can be seen as a constructor and calling `new` on this function will create an object. The problem here is just that this function crashes and stop the code.

Answer (score 0):

This should explain everything

```
<body>
  <script>
    // Defines an object prototype called prose
    function prose(name, company){
      // Any parameter names used inside the constructor must exist in its
      //  signature above
      this.name = name;
      this.company = company;
      // prose.rate is initially set to an empty string because no rate 
      //  argument is passed in 
      this.rate = "";
    }

    // Constructs a new object using the `prose` prototype. (Note that 
    //   JS now also has 'class' syntax available.)
    const y = new prose("JavaScript", "Packt Publishing"); 
       // It would be better to use a more descriptive identifier than `y`

    // Assigns a new value to the rate property of the new object.
    y.rate = 50;


    // We will not use `document.write()` because it replaces all 
    //  existing page content each time it is used
    // The paragraph element (and others) could be included in static 
    //  HTML instead of added dynamically using javascript as we do here

    // Defines nodes to add to the document
    const myParagraph = document.createElement("p");
    const nameText = document.createTextNode("The name of the book is: " + y.name);
    const companyText = document.createTextNode("The name of the publishing company is: " + y.company);
    //priceText includes a fallback string in case y.sellingPrice does not exist
    const priceText = document.createTextNode("The selling price of the book is: " + (y.sellingPrice || "(unknown)"));
    const rateText = document.createTextNode("The rate of the book is: " + y.rate);

    // This function can be called repeatedly to create & append a line break
    function appendLineBreakTo(parentElement){
      const lineBreak = document.createElement("br");
      parentElement.appendChild(lineBreak);
    }

    // Adds all the text nodes inside the newly created paragraph element
    myParagraph.appendChild(nameText);
    appendLineBreakTo(myParagraph); //Calls function to add <br/>

    myParagraph.appendChild(companyText);
    appendLineBreakTo(myParagraph);

    myParagraph.appendChild(priceText);
    appendLineBreakTo(myParagraph);

    myParagraph.appendChild(rateText);
    appendLineBreakTo(myParagraph);

    // Gets a reference to an HTML element that already exists in the DOM
    const body = document.querySelector("body");

    // Adds the paragraph element (with all of its new text nodes) to 
    //  the existing element
    body.appendChild(myParagraph);
  </script>
</body>
```